# Signing off an email with 'on behalf of'?

Tags: formality, business-language, email

I am writing an email as one of the committee members of a voluntary organization. Is this an appropriate way to sign off an informal email whose audience is professionals?

```
Regards,

On behalf of <organization>,
John Doe
```

Comment: _' ... whose audience are professionals' ?_ I think one has to say 'whose audience consists of professionals or we will have a singular/plural argument start up (again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple parts to this question.

The first is whether the three statements, in that order, are syntactically correct. I would say they are. You could use a number of variations in this regard. Each of the following is also correct.

```
On behalf of Organisation,
Regards,
John Doe.
```

and

```
Regards,
John Doe,
On behalf of Organisation.
```

The second part of the question is whether the word choices, as well as word order, are appropriate for the given audience and formality of the letter. This is, of course, subjective, and depends on the public image you wish for the Organisation to portray. You note both that the letter is informal, yet the audience professional and I assume you wish to convey a level of professionalism whilst maintaining the informality. In this regard, in my subjective opinion, I would suggest the latter of my above alternatives. My rationale is that writing "Regards, John Doe" before the organisation name conveys the message just written as coming from a personal perspective. People relate more warmly with people than they do with organisations - so connect as a person first. Following that sign-off with the organisation name maintains the professionalism of the letter. It says that I, John Doe, write to you personally, but I represent Organisation.

A third consideration is localisation of the message. I assume from your spelling of "organization" that you are probably writing in North America and hope your audience is primarily North American. If your audience is British or Australian (or any number of other English speaking backgrounds) a nice touch might be to localise your spelling. In this regard I hope you'll forgive my Australian rendering of many words in which you might normally find a 'z'! If your audience is global, however, such as with a large newsletter, then I would recommend consistency with your own local spellings.

The final consideration that comes to mind is that as John Doe is in fact a fictionally deceased character, I would recommend replacing the name with your own! ;)

Regards,

Chris.